# Converter card for getting data from a MacBook's(MacBook Pro A1502) SSD hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, hardware

I am trying to get the data off the dead MacBook's(MacBook Pro A1502) SSD hard drive.

From my research, I need an SSD adapter as well as a Converter Card. My SSD adapter is Sintech M.2 NGFF 28Pin SSD Adapter([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0173ODBCE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0173ODBCE)) and seems to be the right one.

Which Converter Card should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "Converter card"? External enclosure?

Comment: Something to connect the SSD adapter to the laptop. If you know of any enclosures where you can just put the SSD card and attach it to the laptop, that would be great, as well

Comment: Any external enclosure with USB-3 or USB-C and who accept your adapter. This one, given in your link can do that : https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Type-C-Tool-Free-Enclosure-EC-SNVE/dp/B08RVC6F9Y . But you need a Mac to plug this and  access the data.